# What is the fastest way to calculate a rolling function with a two dimensional window?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas dataframe with two dimensions.  I want to calculate the rolling standard deviation along axis 1 while also including datapoints in the rows above and below.

So say I have this df:

```
data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8],
 'C': [9, 10, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)  

   A  B   C
0  1  5   9
1  2  6  10
2  3  7  11
3  4  8  12
```

I want a rectangular window 3 rows high and 2 columns across, moving from left to right.  So, for example,

```
std_df.loc[1, 'C']
```

would be equal to

```
np.std([1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11])
```

But no idea how to achieve this without very slow iteration

Comment: What type of aggregation are you wanting to use over both axis? I think it's just a matter of building two rolling windows and aggregating those again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you want is [pd.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [5,6,7,8], 'C': [9,10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
   A  B   C
0  1  5   9
1  2  6  10
2  3  7  11
3  4  8  12
```

Shifting the dataframe you provided by 1 yields the row above

```
print(df.shift(1))
     A    B     C
0  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  1.0  5.0   9.0
2  2.0  6.0  10.0
3  3.0  7.0  11.0
```

Similarly, shifting the dataframe you provided by -1 yields the row below

```
print(df.shift(-1))
     A    B     C
0  2.0  6.0  10.0
1  3.0  7.0  11.0
2  4.0  8.0  12.0
3  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

so the code below should do what you're looking for (add_prefix prefixes the column names to make them unique)

```
above_df = df.shift(1).add_prefix('above_')
below_df = df.shift(-1).add_prefix('below_')
lagged = pd.concat([df, above_df, below_df], axis=1)
lagged['std'] = lagged.apply(np.std, axis=1)

print(lagged)
   A  B   C  above_A  above_B  above_C  below_A  below_B  below_C       std
0  1  5   9      NaN      NaN      NaN      2.0      6.0     10.0  3.304038
1  2  6  10      1.0      5.0      9.0      3.0      7.0     11.0  3.366502
2  3  7  11      2.0      6.0     10.0      4.0      8.0     12.0  3.366502
3  4  8  12      3.0      7.0     11.0      NaN      NaN      NaN  3.304038
```

Comment: shifting and then doing a rolling calc worked better than expected. thanks.